# Firebase authentication process

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having problems wrapping my head around the linking of firebase authentication providers.

I have implemented email/password signup as well as Facebook authentication.

Whenever I sign up and log in with Email/password it works 100%. But when I try to log in with Facebook after I have signed up with Email/password I get the message "The email address is already in use by another account."

I am trying to link the facebook account in the following method right after I sign in using email and password.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil{
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            user.link(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else{
                print("SUCCESS")
            }
        }
    }
```

When getting to the "let credential" line it throws an error of undefined.

One more question. When I log in with Facebook, log out again resetting password using Firebase's password reset and trying to log in with email and password should the app still be able to log in with Facebook auth? I tried it before and it didn't log in with Facebook anymore but it logged in with email and password.

Comment: I did not understand what you want to do. Why you want to singIn with email and then with facebook ? it should be either this or that.

Comment: So basically I want to know if it is possible to login with Facebook, log out with Facebook, then log in with email and password, both logins using the same user on firebase?

Comment: No it is not possible. If a user is logged in with a facebook account that uses a@a.com, he cant sign up with this email anymore unless the account is deleted.

Comment: Ah thanx alot,that clears it up. So in short, it will only ever be possible for the user to log in with the account that he has signed up with. So if he signed up with Twitter he will only be able to log in with Twitter as an option right? Unless you delete his account and he signs up with another option.

Comment: yes thats it, there is no other way.

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad: I'm not sure where you got your info. Firebase Authentication allows linking of accounts, so that you can have a single account that is tied to (for example) email+password, Google and Facebook sign-ins. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking

Comment: @user2980509 the user must already be signed in to an existing account to allow linking the other provider.